# Different status bar style in Android 4.4 and 5.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat, material-design, translucentdecor

How to set translucent mode for status bar when app is running on Kitkat device and different-color mode when app is running on Lollipop device?

**Here is my styles.xml in values and values-v21 folder:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#0D47A1</item>
</style>
```

**Here is my styles.xml in values-v19 folder:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#0D47A1</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: create styles.xml in values-xx folder

Comment: @HarshaVardhan I created styles.xml, styles-v19.xml and styles-v21.xml and it doesn't work.

Comment: add code of styles.xml and styles.xml should be in values-{version} folder

Comment: @HarshaVardhan Android Studio doesn't need that. Does it?

Comment: It is not about the IDE, it is about the structure of android. If you want to take styles depend upon the version. we need to follow the structure defined

Comment: @HarshaVardhan I mean that Android Studio do that in its own way: It creates values-{version} folder automatically when you create styles-{version}.xml file.

Comment: you can add the styles.xml code..it will be easy to help u

Answer (score 3):

If you would create different styles for different API versions, you have to use **different folders** instead of different filenames.

```
res/values-vXX
```

You are using styles-v19.xml and styles-v21.xml: it is not the same!

For example use something like:

```
res/values/styles.xml
res/values-v19/styles.xml
res/values-v21/styles.xml
```

Comment: My fault. I didn't show it correctly. I use Android Studio and it hides values-{version} folder. Instead, it simply shows styles.xml (version).

Comment: @ywwynm You are using the "Android" view. In this case you will see styles.xml with (#number) . You can explode this section. If you would like to see the folder structure you can use the "Project" View. Check the view on the top on the left.

Comment: I understand your thought but I'm very sure about that mistakes aren't there. All of my styles.xml are staying where they should be.